# Language versioning PHP Framework

Tags: php, frameworks, translation

I am currently developing a custom PHP framework for a website I am working on. It is a MVC(L) framework and I have most of it in place thus far. I am currently working on URL routing and next I will be looking at language versioning.

What I have is a database filled with data. Every word/sentence has an id, a key and a value for each language.

My website will be launched in several countries so it needs to scale on the number of languages.

So my question is: In your experience, what is the best approach for having a single code base with several languages?

1. Is it to query the database on each word?
2. Load all words from database for each page at one time?
3. To have some sort of file system created for look up, in order to not overload the database.

We are looking at 15.000 visits daily on each site, with each page having a possible number of words to translate over 100.

Has anyone had this challenge and solved it. What is the best approach? Are there any PHP libraries for this?

Best regards,
Rasmus

Comment: Maybe you could take a look on the approach of `Symfony2` translator. They're using a file system where you write down a key => value pair for each language you're supporting. If somebody with a language comes to the site, the keys will be looked up in the certain file, if there is no for this language you'll fall back to a default one (english almost every time)

Comment: I put this answer to a similar question a while back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889181/php-function-for-language-translation/7889418#7889418 - that doesn't actually use a database but that wouldn't be difficult - however, there are an awful lot of gotchas with multi-lingual sites - even with `gettext()` (which is the most efficient solution) : http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php

Comment: This is how Laravel deals with localization, maybe it will give you some ideas: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/localization

Answer (score 0):

For me the best approach would be to generate a static file of all your word for a language, and use this in production. Of course the static file would be generated automatically. You can also imagine caching it in a Memcache server of something similar. Avoid accessing the database.